# JOIN correcto para 2 tablas T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

Resulta que tengo 2 tablas: `Material` y `Reverse`

**Material**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Reverse**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener TODO lo que esta en la tabla `Reverse` mas el nombre del Material en funcion de la tabla `Material` (osea ocupo obtener `A/R FIBERGLASS` y `POLYESTER FELT (12 oz)`

Estoy usando un `INNER JOIN` para obtener esto asi:

```
SELECT rev.id, rev.material, ma.nombreMaterial, rev.aprobado, rev.aros, rev.revision, rev.diametro, rev.largo, rev.top1, rev.bottom, rev.otras, rev.uni_cajas
FROM Reverse rev
INNER JOIN Material ma ON ma.material=rev.material
```

Cuando ejecuto esto me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(No me esta mostrando el registro con `4319`), si por casualidad agrego un WHERE asi:

```
WHERE ma.material='3140'
```

Si me muestra los `3140` pero si cambio el `WHERE` por `4319`, no me muestra nada, que es el fallo que tiene?

Comment: El join lo veo bien... ¿has comprobado que el material 4319 sea el mismo? es decir, que no se haya colado ningún espacio o algo parecido

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser lo que te indica @kilianbs, ¿podrías pasarnos el dataset para comprobarlo? Exporta estas tablas a un fichero SQL y se verá rápidamente

Comment: Comparte la definición de ambas tablas para ver los tipos de datos. Si son cadenas de caracteres, revisa que no haya algo que pueda cambiar el valor de alguna de las 2 columnas. Hay muchos caracteres que no se ven en los resultados de SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta usando un LEFT JOIN, para que te muestre todos los registros que concuerden o no , si usas el inner join solo te mostrará los registros que sean iguales en las 2 tablas

```
SELECT rev.id, rev.material, ma.nombreMaterial, rev.aprobado, rev.aros, rev.revision, rev.diametro, rev.largo, rev.top1, rev.bottom, rev.otras, rev.uni_cajas
FROM Reverse rev
LEFT JOIN Material ma ON ma.material=rev.material
```